# Define a specific column in a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have two different dfs and ks with everything else the same. So I wrote a function to generate data frames seperately. However, it seems like I cannot use k like this. Are there any approaches to solve this problem?

df_1 and df_2 are lists in dataplot.

So I have the same df which is dataplot, and with which I want to define two different k in the function, per and per_hole.

```
sumdata_sd <- function (df,k){
  data.frame (
  per_sd_0 = S,
  per_sd_0.2 = df$df_1$k,
  per_sd_0.5 = df$df_2$k,
)}
plot_per <- sumdata_sd(dataplot,per)
```

reproducible example

```
S <- seq (1,7,1)
dataplot <- list(df_1 = list(per = (seq(1,7,1)),per_hole = (seq(2,8,1))),df_2 = list(per = (seq(3,9,1)),per_hole = (seq(4,10,1))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function we can use `[[` instead of `$` if we pass a string

```
sumdata_sd <- function (df,k){
  data.frame (
   per_sd_0 = S,
  per_sd_0.2 = df$df_1[[k]],
  per_sd_0.5 = df$df_2[[k]]
)}

sumdata_sd(dataplot, "per")
```